# Unable to display tableView in iOS app

Tags: objective-c

I am fairly new to iOS and am attempting to display a tableView controller from another tableView controller in a drill down routine for an iPad app.  However, the new tableView will not display.  I can follow the program logic through the following routine in debug mode but after this logic, the same view remains on the screen. I set breakpoints in the new tableview program to be displayed and they are never reached. I have included the `HEDView.h` in the application file for this program and have no clue why the new view is not displayed.  Any help is or suggestions for more info is appreciated.

Here is the routine to call the tableView:  HEDView will not display.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    HEDView *detailViewController = [[HEDView alloc] initWithNibName:@"HEDView" bundle:nil];

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    detailViewController.title = @"HEDView";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];   
    [detailViewController release];   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to navigate to other viewcontroller when cell in the row is selected, then I think your navigationcontroller is not properly allocated.While debugging check whether self.navigationController is returning proper address.If not then you have to first properly allocate it.

and one more thing, HEDView is UIViewController so you should follow proper naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` in AppDelegate.m, and also include `@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navControl;` in AppDelegate.h

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {

        self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        navControl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];


        [self.window addSubview:[navControl view]];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }
```

I think it will be helpful to you.